# Whats a simple Perl script to parse a HTML document with custom tags(Perl interpreter)?

Tags: perl, html-parser

Ok this is what I'm doing. I'm making a perl interpreter for documents that end in my custom extension(.cpm). I have looked around and found

- http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/html_parser.html
- https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TokeParser::Simple
- http://www.justskins.com/forums/html-parser-8489.html

It seems that [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aParser) is the way to go. What I am asking for is a simple tutorial to parse a document with special tags. For example I would like something that shows me how to parse a HTML document but whenever the `<putinbold>` is ecountered it replaces it with `<b>`.

An example of what I want-

`<html>`
`This is HTML talking`
`<liamslanguage>say "This is Liams language speaking"</liamslanguage>`
`</html>`

Comment: How about a sample of the html you want to parse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important part of parsing with [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aParser) is to assign the right `handlers` with the right `argspec`. A sample program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;

my $html;
sub replace_tagname {
    my ( $tagname, $event ) = @_;

    if ( $tagname eq 'liamslanguage' ) {
        $tagname = 'b';
    }

    if ( $event eq 'start' ) {
        $html .= "<$tagname>";
    }
    elsif ( $event eq 'end' ) {
        $html .= "</$tagname>";
    }
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
    'api_version' => 3,
    'start_h'     => [ \&replace_tagname,      'tagname, event' ],
    'default_h'   => [ sub { $html .= shift }, 'text'           ],
    'end_h'       => [ \&replace_tagname,      'tagname, event' ],
);
$p->parse( do { local $/; <DATA> } );
$p->eof();

print $html;

__DATA__
<html>
This is HTML talking
<liamslanguage>say "This is Liams language speaking"</liamslanguage>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. This is very useful and informative. Thumbs up!

Comment: Oh another question. How would I get the data between the tags?

Comment: Liam E-p: Use different callbacks for the start and end handlers. In the start handler, set a flag so that you know that a tag has started. In the callback for the default handler, check if the flag has been set. If so, the text is between the tags. In the end handler, reset the flag. There probably might be another way. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Liam E-p: I have updated the code so that it takes care of end tags. I somehow overlooked it.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. I use a .htaccess file to firstly use this script to handle .cpm files. Then using "$ENV{'PATH_TRANSLATED'};" I can find the file refered and open it. Then I just parse it with this script.